# Uso das palavras incisivo e porém

Tags: significado

Quero escrever a seguinte frase:

> Incisivo não? Porém, verdadeiro

Tenho dúvidas se estou usando as palavas e pontuações corretas. Sendo que essa frase é referente ao tema "solidão", fala de como é, e como podemos lidar com ela.

Comment: poderia colocar mais partes do texto? Apenas com isso, fica difícil entender o contexto todo. Mas incisivo me parece q tem a ideia de "Sem rodeios", indo "direto ao ponto", Porém dá a idéia de "oposição ou restrição"

Comment: O texto é esse ->Por vezes a "solidão" pode nos provocar receio, insegurança e um certo desconforto, mas certamente ela não nos fere tanto quanto a ilusão que provocam as falsas companhias. Por isso, procure antes o colo de Deus do que se jogar nos braços de um(a) qualquer.

Comment: Eu entendi que queres perguntar se está "indo muito direto ao ponto", depois negar isso, e posteriormente dizer que está sendo verdadeiro. Se é esse o sentido, escreveria assim:Incisivo? Não, porém, verdadeiro.

Comment: Pelo que entendi: pergunta se é incisivo, utilizando o 'não', como 'não é?'/'né?', então cria uma antitese ao afirmar que é verdadeiro. Nesse caso, seria "Incisivo, não é? Entretanto, é verdadeiro.". Em fala mais casual e abreviada: "Incisivo, não? Mas verdadeiro.".

Answer (score 1):

Você pergunta se é incisivo, utilizando o 'não', como 'não é?'/'né?', então cria uma antítese ao afirmar que é verdadeiro. Nesse caso, seria:

> "Incisivo, não é? Entretanto, é verdadeiro.".

Em fala mais casual e abreviada:

> "Incisivo, não? Mas verdadeiro.".